# What is the difference of char[] c and char c[]?

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, char

As I wrote in the title I'm confused how to declare a char array, and the result from the search is

1.`char[] c`

2.`char c[]`

The second one is similar to me because I learnt it in college. If the first one is legal, could I do something like `char[5] c`?

Comment: What happens when you try `char[5] c`?

Comment: I can't try now, I'm in the lecture now, not in the lab.

Comment: because I'm learning the basic of programming, the lecturer is talking about array. I did learn C++ 4 yrs ago. Now what I search is all relate to c#.

Comment: do you realize that they are *different languages*? And that syntax that is valid in one language might not be valid in another language? Make up your mind, **which language are you asking about**?

Comment: @logger I'm changing the tag from .net to c#, because only one of these things is a language

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize the language problem. In the c++ language, what is the correct one?

Comment: Is your teacher teaching C++ or C#? Is he actually teaching a language at all? That's what you should care about :)

Comment: He is teaching the theory now. I try some search but it is not what I remember about c++. The results are about C# lol. My bad.

Comment: @logger c++ and c# share a few keywords and they both use curly braces... that's about it: they are separate languages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) terms:

```
char[] c
```

This is a regular field or local declaration, that declares `c` to be of type `char[]`.

```
char c[]
```

This is not legal in any context.

> If the first one is legal, could I do something like `char[5] c`?

Normally, you would do something like:

```
char[] c = new char[5];
```

or identically:

```
var c = new char[5];
```

The `char[5] c` syntax you cite not valid. There *is* a syntax `fixed char c[5]` - but that is not an array - it is a *fixed buffer* (where `c` is now an unsafe `char*` pointer to a reserved block in an `unsafe struct` large enough for 5 `char` values, so 10 bytes).

Comment: Thank a lot for the answer, I misunderstood the problem about the C++ and C#.

Answer (score 0):

`char[]` c is wrong. If you try `char[5] c` in visual studio, you will get error like

> empty attribute block is not allowed.

I think only `char c[]` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

In the C(++) world:

This depends very much on how tolerant your compiler is. In some cases, `[]` is little more but a more intent-showing way of writing `*`. C-style arrays aren't "really" arrays, they're just a pointer to the first element of a set of vaguely typed data.

With the shift to more intent shown in code, the difference between the simple `char *c` and `char []c` (which is not valid for many, perhaps even most compilers) and `char c[]` is blown up a bit more. That said, this is not a *technological* limitation - it's still just a pointer, and you can use `c[5]` with `char *c` the same way as with `char c[]`.

A slightly different variant is an array with static length, eg. `char c[5]`. This has a more significant difference from the simple `char *c`. It's still just a pointer, but you don't allocate it manually. It has its benefits and limitations.

In any case, `char[] c`, even if it was syntactically correct in your compiler (it might be in C++.NET), would be a bad notation as far as C/C++ is concerned, since it implies that the "arrayness" of the variable is in the "type", which isn't actually true.

The usual example is like this; in C#:

```
char[] a, b;
```

declares two char arrays, `a` and `b`. However, in C:

```
char* a, b;
```

declares one char pointer, and one char variable.

That said, I could believe that it's the valid and proper way in C++.NET / C++/CLI. If it does follow the .NET standards, it's quite likely.

**A huge disclaimer**: do not confuse different C-style languages. They tend to be very different. C# in particular is extremely different, and a lot of the syntax is changed, and the same keywords may mean something completely different.

C++ is built on top of C (so C code mostly works in C++), and the same is true for eg. Objective-C. C# stands completely outside of this environment. It's not an extension, it's just inspired by some of the style (eg. the curly braces), but very, very different. In the end, it's probably closer to (Object) Pascal than to C(++), even though visually it looks much closer to C.